# SQL/HQL Count Total Not Working on Join

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I'm creating a recommender using some simple probability formulas.  I'm working with the [Million Song Dataset](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/) large dataset (189M rows and 3 columns) with my Hadoop cluster, using Hive.  Here is a sample of the initial dataset:

million_song - initial dataset

```
 user   song    play_count
 c3fb2  SOXOQ   18
 c3fb2  SOZVC   1
 6041e  SOBHN   3
 6041e  SOBXT   5
```

But first I created a table from the initial dataset, which a sample is show here:

million_both - adds up occurrence of two songs listened by same user

```
 driver_song_id     also_song_id    play_count
 SOXOQ              SOBXT           1642
 SOBHN              SOBXT           2168
 SOBXT              SOZVC           1742
```

get all distinct users (I want this value displayed in all rows in fifth column of final output)

```
 select count(distinct users) from million_song;
 # 139,738,054
```

I'm trying to add these two tables above together, and the issue is I can't get the correct count_n_users, which should be the same # for each row in the table.  Here is my code:

```
 select a.driver_song_id, a.also_song_id, a.play_count, 
 count(distinct b.user), sum(distinct b.user) as count_n_users 
 from (select driver_song_id, also_song_id, play_count from million_both) as a 
 join (select user, song, play_count from expp_team.million_song) as b 
 on a.driver_song_id = b.song
 group by a.driver_song_id, a.also_song_id, a.play_count;
```

The issue I cannot get the correct count_n_users, as of right now it's overstating the value.

This is what I'd like the output to look like:

```
 driver_song_id     also_song_id    play_count  c(b.user)  count_n_users
 SOXOQ              SOBXT           1643        463         139,738,054           
 SOBHN              SOBXT           2168        483         139,738,054
 SOBXT              SOZVC           1742        725         139,738,054
```

Comment: Can you edit w/ sample data that actually illustrates why you expect that output? I don't know what "adding these two tables together" means. For instance, in your first row of expected output, how is `play_count` 1,643?

Comment: What is *count_n_users* supposed to return? How is it different from the second last column?

Comment: @Codo count_n_users is suppose to represent the count(distinct users) in million_song (the initial dataset)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia the last output I listed is what I would expect.  The first four columns are correctly outputted by the SQL above, but I'm unable to get the fifth column.

Comment: Then you will have to explain how you get what you expect from the data you provided. It's obviously not clear from what you've posted. 1642 + 18 does not equal 1643. 1642 + 5 does not equal 1643. The net of the two does not equal 1643. And obviously this 139.7 million figure cannot be derived from anything you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query is currently returning all of the correct output except for that column and that column should have the same value on all rows of the result set, and it can be returned by running a query that just counts all distinct users from the `million_song` table you can add a `cross join` with the query that grabs that total count. This avoids the issue with the `group by` which is what you're probably experiencing.

```
select a.driver_song_id,
       a.also_song_id,
       a.play_count,
       count(distinct b.user),
       c.count_n_users
  from (select driver_song_id,
               also_song_id,
               play_count
          from million_both) as a
  join (select user,
               song,
               play_count
          from expp_team.million_song) as b
    on a.driver_song_id = b.song
 cross join (select count(distinct users) as count_n_users from million_song) c
 group by a.driver_song_id,
          a.also_song_id,
          a.play_count;
```